# Variable in thread doesn't change with the variable of class

Tags: python

My server class is listening for clients :

```
def listen_for_clients(self):
    self.sock.settimeout(1)
    while 1:
        try:
            print 'listening for clients'
            print self.quit_time
            if self.quit_time: break
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
            conn.setblocking(1)
            self.connections.append(conn)
            thread.start_new_thread(self.client_listener,(conn, ))  
        except socket.timeout:
            pass
```

However when I change the boolean self.quit_time to True it still prints as false in the thread and doesn't break out. Why is that?

Here's the code that changes the value of self.quit_time:

```
def close(self):
    self.quit_time = True
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'closing:', self
    if self.incoming_thread:
        self.incoming_thread.join()
        print 'incoming thread joined'
    if self.outgoing_thread:
        self.outgoing_thread.join()
        print 'outgoing thread joined'
    if self.listener_thread:
        self.listener_thread.join()
        print 'listener thread joined'
    for c in self.connections:
        if c:
            c.close()
    if self.sock:
        self.sock.close()
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre made the change and fixed the typo. It's quit_time

Comment: ok, this _must_ be the same instance of the same class, of course. Try to print `id(self.quit_time)` in both snippets. If they're not identical, no communication!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Better he should print out `id(self)` because `id(self.quit_time)` is the id of _the_ `True` or `False` object (both objects exist only once).

Comment: ok I printed the ids of both self and the object. Neither are the same: ID in MAIN 495006804 48089488
ID in thread 495006596 48157968

Comment: @bkarj `self` isn't the same instance or class then. If so, maybe use a global boolean (urgh!!) to communicate.

Comment: well that just confused the hell out of me cause I only created one instance of that class.

Comment: I've actually created 2 instances for two separate servers with different ports. But here's what I don't get: in def __init__ i added print id(self) and print id(self.quit_time). When I instantiate the two servers it prints differnt ids for self, but the same is for self.quit_time: CREATING 44738320
quit time 500708228
CREATING 44740496
quit time 500708228

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't understand your point. Can you elaborate. Why is the boolean variable returning the same id for all the same instances of the class? Isn't it a different location in memory?

Comment: @bkarj `self.quit_time` references a boolean object, either `True` or `False`. These two objects are created on Python startup and are returned everywhere where needed, no new boolean objects are created. Therefore `id(self.quit_time)` will always return the id of one of the two only existing boolean objects.

Comment: did not know that. thank you